# How to define my function to preserve geom_point + geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want use my function f() about ggplot, but it doesn't successfully work.
Please tell me how to solve this.

```
f= function(){
   geom_point() + geom_line() 
}

data_frame = tibble(y_axis = c(1,2,3,1,1,1), 
                    x_axis = c("AD", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                    g = c("buy", "sell", "buy", "sell", "buy", "sell"))

g2 <- ggplot(data_frame, aes(x=x_axis, y=y_axis, colour = g,group =  g)) + f()

g2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to `ggplot` objects with a function, but it must be in the form of a list.  So this is what you need:

```
f <- function() {
    list(geom_point(), geom_line())
}
```

Just add that to any `ggplot` object as you have indicated in your code.  Ex:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + f()
```